# How to implement oracle order by decode in JPA criteria builder

Tags: spring-data-jpa, sql-order-by, decode, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

I wanted to implememt Oracle order by Decode functionality in JPA criteria builder.

Did not get any clue on how to

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.